# How to display an image and kill it after 1.5 seconds?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am making a game in python, and am displaying an image. I would use pygame, but the effects I am making won't be used in pygame. I looked it up and used pillow because it requires the least code. Open vc looked a little complicated.

```py
from PIL import Image
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('python imviewer.py')
img  = Image.open(r'C:\Users\gudip\Ayush_codes_and_programs_in_python\Ninjago\striking_rabbit.png')
img.show()
time.sleep(1.25)
p.kill()
```

```py
import time
from playsound import playsound 
from os import system, name
from PIL import Image
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('python imviewer.py')
level = 0
story = False
game_over = False
save_game = False
ninja_name = ''
game1 = True

def intro(ninja_name):
    print("Garmadon! What is he up to now?")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Jay, does it matter? Whatever he's doing, it's going to help conquer ninjago")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Duh, Cole. But how can we stop it?")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Guys, guys. Calm down. We'll need as many ninja as we can get to stop Garmadon")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("See Cole! You DON'T need to know what he's doing")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Hey! I said that!")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Hey, is that a ninja right there?")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Yeah, you. Whats your name?")
    ninja = input("Which ninja do you want to play as? [K]ai, [C]ole, [Z]ane, [L]loyd, or [J]ay? ")
    if ninja in 'k':
        print("Ok Kai. Start your mission!")
        ninja_name = 'Kai'
        training(ninja_name)
    elif ninja in 'c':
        print("Ok Cole. Start your mission!")
        ninja_name = 'Cole'
        training(ninja_name)
    elif ninja in 'z':
        print("Ok Zane. Start your mission!")
        ninja_name = 'Zane'
        training(ninja_name)
    elif ninja in 'l':
        print("Ok Lloyd. Start your mission!")
        ninja_name = 'Lloyd'
        training(ninja_name)
    elif ninja in 'j':
        print("Ok Jay. Start your mission!")
        ninja_name = 'Jay'
        training(ninja_name)
    else:
        print(f'''
{ninja} is not a valid option.
Please enter either k for kai, c for cole, z for zane, l for lloyd, and j for jay.
Please know, Nya doesn't know her elemental powers yet, and your elemental power is required to play the game.
This is why nya is not a legible character.''')
        intro()

def training(ninja_name):
    print(f"Ok. You all know the drill. I'm going to teach {ninja_name.title()} how things work around here.")
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print("Together : Ok master Wu!")
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print("Ok. First, you need to train. Let's learn the art of the striking rabbit.")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    playsound(r'C:\Users\gudip\Ayush_codes_and_programs_in_python\Ninjago\audio.mp3')
    img  = Image.open(r'C:\Users\gudip\Ayush_codes_and_programs_in_python\Ninjago\striking_rabbit.png')
    img.show()
    time.sleep(1.25)
    p.kill()
    
intro(ninja_name)
```

That is where my code is. I don't know where to put the openvc code as someone suggested in here.

Comment: You should look into opencv. There is a **waitKey()** and **destroyAllWindows()** which can be used for this task

Comment: This would be relatively easy to do with the [`tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#module-tkinter) module, although you'd have to write a few lines of code…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using OpenCV. `waitKey` waits for a key press but also has a timeout in milliseconds. Here is the code:

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("test.png")
cv2.imshow("Window", image)
cv2.waitKey(1250)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDdttJXlLtAJxJetJcqmqlQq&v=Z78zbnLlPUA&feature=emb_title) is a tutorial how to install opencv.

---

You can also use `Tkinter`. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("test.png"))
label = tk.Label(root, image = img).pack()

root.after(1250, lambda: root.destroy())
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't know this interface. Does `waitKey(1250)` wait 1.5 seconds? Is there a good way to know how to scale seconds to the wait key value?

Comment: waitKey is in milliseconds, the OP had 1.25 seconds, so that would be 1250 milliseconds

Comment: Oh, I saw 1.5 seconds in the title.

Comment: So, `time.sleep(1.5)` if you don't want the image to be interruptable?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need a `waitkey` to display the image

Comment: But you can make a really short waitkey, then you can have a `time.sleep` before `destroyAllWindows()`